# Parse: selectKeys method not working

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I'd like to retrieve only certain columns from Parse. But it downloads the whole objects instead:

```
            let usersQuery = PFQuery(className: "_User")
            usersQuery.whereKey("userId", containedIn: self.memberIds!) // Array of Strings containing the userIds
            usersQuery.selectKeys(["email"])
            usersQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error)
                } else if let users = objects as? [PFUser] {

                    print("objects: \(users)")

                    // prints whole object, not only "email" field
                }
            })
```

The output:

```
objects: [<PFUser: 0x7fb1095a7270, objectId: 9Ld9vRPoLZ, localId: (null)> {
email = "iphone5s@mail.com";
fullname = "iPhone 5S";
// ... other fields

}]
```

Comment: What does it print exactly?  A PFUser object has all fields -- are they set or are you getting a bunch for blanks and nils?

Comment: See updated question.

Comment: is `... other fields` a bunch of nils or real data?

Comment: Real data. The empty fields on parse.com don't get downloaded.

Comment: Anyone a clue? I tried it with a different class where it worked. This is quite surprising because I think I had tried it out some time ago where it worked.

Comment: I tried it again with another class. It worked there now (don't know why), but selecting keys from `_User` class is still not working.